# Docker COPY not working and permissions issues

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have read countless posts and can't figure out why COPY isn't working or permissions/ownership aren't changing.

My dockerfile is as follow (simplified)

```
FROM somealpineimage as prod

USER root
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/test
WORKDIR /home/node/app
COPY package*json ./
COPY ./src/folder/tests /home/node/app/test # <- this guy here nothing happens tried multiple variations
RUN npm install
COPY . . # I assumed this command would copy everything from project directory to image but doesn't

FROM prod
RUN npm prune --production
COPY . .
USER node
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

This particular folder I'm trying to copy is to resolve a permissions issue.

My initial thought was to copy the contents of tests folder to test with added --chown=node:node   to set the correct ownership. But I can't seem to get the ownership to change.

I've tried chmod -R 777 as root user didn't work either.
Like so:

```
USER root
RUN chmod -R 777 /home/node/app/tests
# or with a higher folder
RUN chmod -R 777 /home/node # with -R it should recursively change permissions but it did nothing
```

The dockerfile is in the root directory of the project

```
project
├── Dockerfile
├── src
│   ├── begin-with-the-crazy-ideas.textile
│   └── isn't-docker-supposed-to-make-it-easier.markdown
├── tests
│   ├── test1.test
    └── test2.test
```

The reason I need these files with different ownership is my Node app can't edit/open/unzip/zip them since they're owned by root and nodejs app runs under the user node. Don't have the option to run as root and it would be bad practice.

Any help I'd appreciate. For now I'll go research.

**Note** : the project is written/tested on a M1 MacOS Docker but the official container runs on Kubernetes/Linux I have permissions issues only when deployed.

Comment: What permission issue? Show the commands and their output that demonstrate the issue.

Comment: The files should be owned by root and not world-writeable.  That's a very normal setup that prevents the application from overwriting its own source code, intentionally or otherwise.  Can you move this writeable data to another directory?  Are you launching the container with some sort of mount that hides the image content?

Comment: @BMitch Read/Write and it's the nodejs app that's causing this trigger since it is trying to open a file.

Comment: @DavidMaze You're right. Root makes everything. All I care about is changing permissions for the app (source code folder), it also contains the files that are edited. Since we can't run the app as root (not allowed + bad) the default node user is meant to run the app. I've got to where all the files have node as the owner except the files that need changing which makes no sense.